# jQuery change background image - Quotation marks

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I have a small jQuery function where i can change background image to a div.

**HTML + jQuery**

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>

<a onclick="chooseBackground('foo.jpg')">Foo!</a>

<script>    
function chooseBackground(file) {
       var file = '/path/to/'+file;
       $('#mydiv').css('background-image','url('+file+')');
    }
</script>
```

**The result of this in Chrome inspector is:**

```
<div id="mydiv" style="background-image: url("/path/to/foo.jpg");"></div>
```

**I have also tried this:**

```
$("#mydiv").css("background-image","url('"+file+"')");
```

The quotatation marks is there instead of apostrophe marks what should wrap the url.

The result is the same on booth scripts. Any ideas here? Am I missing something obvious?

**[Edit] Why this is a problem**

I have another script that previews the whole div. The script copy all the content in the div (including the background image) and show it in full screen. Like this:

```
<script>
function preview() {
    var background = $('#mydiv').css('background-image');
    var content = 'foo bar abc 123';
    $('#previewdiv').html('<div style="background-image:'+background+';">'+content+'</div>';
}
<script>
```

The result in HTML is:

```
  <div style="background-image: url(" http:="" mydomain.com="" path="" to="" foo.jpg");">
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry. Edited the question. I wrote wrong here on Stackoverflow

Comment: The code you've provided works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/mx3tv69m/. What is the issue with having the quotations in the HTML?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: The result in the inspector is the same: <div id="mydiv" style="background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/kPYfVBO.jpg");"></div>. Is it the Chrome inspector that is wierd?

Comment: Possibly, but is there a specific problem with the code?

Comment: Yes. I have a preview button that copy the content in the div (including the background image) and show it in full screen. The background image url then is like: background-image: url(" http:="" mydomain.com="" path="" to="" foo.jpg");"

Comment: The issue is with that code block then - could you edit your question to include it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Edited

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
function chooseBackground(file) {
    var file = 'http://icons.iconseeker.com/png/128/soccer-teams/' + file;
    $('#mydiv').css('background-image', 'url(' + file + ')');
}
    
function preview() {
    var background = $('#mydiv').css('background-image');
    var content = $('#mydiv').html();
    $('#previewdiv').html(content).css('background-image', background);
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        background-size: cover;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    #previewdiv {
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background-size: cover;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">Foo! Div</div><br/>
<div id="previewdiv">Previw div</div>

<a onclick="chooseBackground('barcelona-fc-logo.png')">Foo!</a>
|
<a onclick="preview()">Preview</a>
```